# Error connecting to DBFit database : "DbEnvironmentFactory.getDefaultEnvironment()" is null

Tags: java, fitnesse, dbfit

I try connecting to Oracle database with DbFit version 3.2.0

I've start with a postgres Sample

```
!|Database environment|${DB_ENVIRONMENT}                                                                                       |
|Connect              |jdbc:postgresql://${DB_URL}/${DB_SID}?currentSchema=${DB_SCHEMA}&user=${DB_USER}&password=${DB_PASSWORD}|
```

that I adapted to

```
!|Database environment|${DB_ENVIRONMENT}                                                                                       |
|Connect              |jdbc:oracle:thin:${DB_USER}/${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_URL}/${DB_SID}
```

DB_ENVIRONMET was set to POSTGREJSON that I've changed to ORACLE
and I had an error message :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "dbfit.api.DBEnvironment.getConnection()" because the return value of "dbfit.api.DbEnvironmentFactory.getDefaultEnvironment()" is null
```

I've found that some was using

```
!|dbfit.OracleTest|
```

but I still have the same error message.

I suppose that I need to set 'database environment' to the right values, but did not found any information.
Can anyone help?